# Access a file with a $variable-unix

Tags: file, variables, unix, cat, dollar-sign

I am trying to access a file that has a variable in its name (i.e. file_n: file_1, file_2, etc). I am trying to access it with

```
cat $file_$n
```

But this doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `$` from file, use `cat file_$n` instead to view the content of the file.

Comment: @WillMcConnell- If this answer helps, please don't forget to accept the answer. See how to accept the answer ---> http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work